# Nokogiri: Ignoring child nodes

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an xml document like the following:

```
<doc>
  <header>
    <group>
      <note>group note</note>
    </group>
    <note>header note</note>
  </header>
</doc>
```

I want to retrieve the note elements that fall under header and not any note elements that fall under group.

I thought this should work but it also picks up the note under group:

```
 doc.css('header note')
```

What is the syntax to only grab the note element that is the direct child of the header?

Comment: I assume the second "<group>" tag is supposed to be a closing tag - "</group>"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `>` in CSS-selectors to find child elements. This is in contrast to using a space, , which finds descendant elements.

In your case:

```
puts doc.css('header > note')
#=> "<note>header note</note>"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to let Nokogiri find all `header note` tags, then only use the last one:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<doc>
  <header>
    <group>
      <note>group note</note>
    <group>
    <note>header note</note>
  </header>
</doc>
EOT

doc.css('header note').last.text # => "header note"
```

Remember, `css`, like its XPath counterpart `xpath`, and the more generic `search`, return NodeSets. NodeSets are like an Array in that you can slice it or use `first` or `last` with it.

Note though, you could just as easily use:

```
doc.css('note').last.text # => "header note"
```

Notice though, your XML is malformed. The `<group>` tag isn't closed. Nokogiri is doing fixups to the XML, which can give you odd results. Check for that situation by looking at `doc.errors`:

```
# => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: group line 5 and header>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: group line 3 and doc>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag header line 2>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag doc line 1>]
```